# Jbehave boolean named parameter

Tags: java, automated-tests, jbehave

In the jbehave 3 examples I can see parameters as "double", so I tried to use other types besides string, but when I try to add a boolean parameter like this

```
public void theUserShouldBeRedirectedToHomePage(@Named("should?") boolean should)
```

I get an argument type error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbehave.scenario.steps.CandidateStep$1.perform(CandidateStep.java:225)
    at org.jbehave.scenario.ScenarioRunner$FineSoFar.run(ScenarioRunner.java:112)
```

(also, I'm using version 2.3, not 3 of jbehave)

Is it a problem with my jbehave version? which is the right way to use a boolean parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this too. There is no default ParameterConverter for boolean/Boolean. You can easily add one.

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parameter-converters.html

Comment: That is pretty unfortunate because boolean type seems to be mapped perfectly into its string counterpart. Hope they make it is default converter in next release

Answer (score 0):

If you will pass this parameter to other method anyways, sometimes is easier to do like this:

public void theUserShouldBeRedirectedToHomePage(@Named("should?") **String** should){

myNextMethod(**Boolean.valueOf(should)**);
}

Answer (score 0):

Jbehave version 3 works well with Boolean. Take the following example it works perfectly fine in my code.

```
@Then("I verify the response has _success as $_success and _warning as $_warning and _info as $_info and _messages as $_messages")
            public void pidOrPidColorDeleteResponse(
                    @Named("_success") Boolean _success,
                    @Named("_warning") Boolean _warning, 
                    @Named("_info") Boolean _info,
                    @Named("_messages") List<String> _messages) { 

            }
```

With Jbehave Version 2 need to check.